# JSON object being changed when sent to node server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Using this code I have created a function that creates some JSON data and sends it to server.js (my node server).

```
function deleteEmail(i) {
    emailObj.splice(i, 1);
    var general = {};
    var table = []
    general.table = table;
    for (var i = 0; i < emailObj.length; i++) {
      var dataHtml = emailObj[i].html;
      var html = {
        "html": dataHtml
      }
      general.table.push(html);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(general));
    $.post("email2", general);
  }
```

The code within server.js to catch the JSON data is this:

```
app.post("/email2", function(req, res){
   console.log(req.body);
});
```

Here is the JSON data created by the function and sent to server.js:

```
{"table":[{"html":"<b>ID email:</b> #1481145671503<br><b>Form journey:</b> General<br><b>Work Request Title:</b> <br><b>Data Request:</b> <br><b>Request By:</b> <br><b>Department:</b> <i>not specified</i><br><b>Business Owner:</b> <br><b>Contact Details:</b> <br><b>Request Overview:</b> <br><b>Platform Impacted:</b> undefined<br><b>Business Objectives:</b> <br><b>Business Benefits Justifications:</b> <br><b>Project Drive:</b> <br><b>Additional Information:</b> <br>"},{"html":"<b>ID email:</b> #1481214851188<br><b>Date:</b> Thu Dec 08 2016 16:34:11 GMT+0000 (GMT)<br><b>Form journey:</b> General<br><b>Work Request Title:</b> <br><b>Data Request:</b> <br><b>Request By:</b> <br><b>Department:</b> <i>not specified</i><br><b>Business Owner:</b> <br><b>Contact Details:</b> <br><b>Request Overview:</b> <br><b>Platform Impacted:</b> undefined<br><b>Business Objectives:</b> <br><b>Business Benefits Justifications:</b> <br><b>Project Drive:</b> <br><b>Additional Information:</b> <br>"}]}
```

And here is the JSON data that the server is receiving:

```
 { 'table[0][html]': '<b>ID email:</b> #1481145671503<br><b>Form journey:</b> General<br><b>Work Request Title:</b> <br><b>Data Request:</b> <br><b>Request By:</b> <br><b>Department:</b> <i>not specified</i><br><b>Business Owner:</b> <br><b>Contact Details:</b> <br><b>Request Overview:</b> <br><b>Platform Impacted:</b> undefined<br><b>Business Objectives:</b> <br><b>Business Benefits Justifications:</b> <br><b>Project Drive:</b> <br><b>Additional Information:</b> <br>',
  'table[1][html]': '<b>ID email:</b> #1481214851188<br><b>Date:</b> Thu Dec 08 2016 16:34:11 GMT+0000 (GMT)<br><b>Form journey:</b> General<br><b>Work Request Title:</b> <br><b>Data Request:</b> <br><b>Request By:</b> <br><b>Department:</b> <i>not specified</i><br><b>Business Owner:</b> <br><b>Contact Details:</b> <br><b>Request Overview:</b> <br><b>Platform Impacted:</b> undefined<br><b>Business Objectives:</b> <br><b>Business Benefits Justifications:</b> <br><b>Project Drive:</b> <br><b>Additional Information:</b> <br>' }
```

Why is it doing this and how can I keep the exact same formatting and data when sending it too and interpretting it by server.js.

Thanks

Comment: A few things you can check - explicitly setting the content type to `application/json` in jquery when sending the request and also checking the body parser middleware in the node.js application. It seems that the issue is most likely to be in one of those two places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never send JSON data to the server.

> ```
> console.log(JSON.stringify(general));
> ```

In the above line you:

1. Take `general`, a JavaScript object
2. Convert it to JSON
3. Log it

> ```
> $.post("email2", general);
> ```

In the above line you pass `general` (still not JSON!) to `$.post`.

When you pass `post` an object, jQuery will convert it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded data and send that.

---

If you want to send JSON, then you need to:

- Say you are sending JSON
- Actually send JSON

Such:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "email2",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(general),
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Fairly new to ajax, i'll know for next time.